# N random numbers are chosen from an IID, what's the probability that each consecutive number is smaller than the next?

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

$X_1, X_2, X_3,\dots, X_n$ are $n$ [independent and identically distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)

What's the value of the following probability?

$$\Bbb P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4 < \dots < X_n)$$

To solve it I simplified the problem to just $\Bbb P(X_1 < X_2)$. Still I couldn't think of any solution because $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is a huge range. I can't even think of how the integration will work in this case.

1. If you have any idea on how such problems are solved please share.
2. Also if you have links to where I can study more such problems please share that as well.

Comment: As long as the distribution is continuous, the variables are as likely to be in increasing order as in any other particular order.

Comment: Consider the distribution:
$\mathbb{P}(X_1=0)=.7$
$\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=.3$

$\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2) = \mathbb{P}(X_1=0\wedge X_2=1) = .7\cdot .3$

So, as Lord Shark the Unknown said, it probably requires that the distributions be continuous.

In general, in the case of $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2)$, you may be able to write:

$\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X_2=x)\mathbb{P}(X_1<x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $n=2$ and let $h$ be the common probability density function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ **(assuming they are continuous)**. Since they are independent, we have:
$$\Bbb P(X_1<X_2) = \iint_{x_1<x_2} h(x_1)h(x_2)\text{d}x_1\text{d}x_2 = \int_{x_2=-\infty}^{x_2=+\infty}\left(\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{x_1=x_2} h(x_1)\text{d}x_1\right)h(x_2)\text{d}x_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bbb P(X_1<x_2) h(x_2)\text{d}x_2$$
using Fubini. Of course, we can also write:
$$\Bbb P(X_1<X_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bbb P(X_2>x_1) h(x_1)\text{d}x_1.$$